# javascript:history.back() on pages and not events

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview

I have an ASPX page that contains a link to "javascript:history.back()"

The problem is that page contains a gridview that changes with events (ex. a column is sorted). Now when I click the link to "javascript:history.back()", it just reverses the event but instead I want to go back to the last page (bypassing all the events).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to save the referring page's URL when your page first gets called.  Then use this URL in your "Back" links.

Comment: And as an added bonus, this could still work even when JavaScript is disabled...!